# How can I destroy Observable on unSubscribe in RxJava?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I've got the following class:

```
public class Service {

    private Observable<Long> obs = Observable.interval(0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    private Single<Foo> sendFooRequest() {
        return Single.fromCallable(() -> sendHttpRequest());
    }

    public Flowable<Foo> getFlowable() {
        return obs
                .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
                .doOnNext(tick -> log.info("tick: {}", tick))
                .flatMapSingle(tick -> sendFooRequest())
                .distinctUntilChanged();
    }
}
```

Every time a new client connects, `getFlowable()` gets called. So there's the following situation:

```
client #1 connects -> disconnects
client #2 connects -> disconnects
client #3 connects
```

And the output looks the following:

```
17:33:58.826  INFO 11813 --- [nio-6969-exec-3] ...Service  : tick: 0
17:34:01.162  INFO 11813 --- [ionThreadPool-2] ...Service  : tick: 19
17:34:02.918  INFO 11813 --- [ionThreadPool-1] ...Service  : tick: 94
17:34:03.827  INFO 11813 --- [ionThreadPool-3] ...Service  : tick: 1
17:34:06.162  INFO 11813 --- [ionThreadPool-2] ...Service  : tick: 20
17:34:07.919  INFO 11813 --- [ionThreadPool-1] ...Service  : tick: 95
```

So it looks like even though there's only one active subscriber, the app still uses 3 threads (and processes 3 observables), and the app does create only one instance of `Service`.

How can I *destroy* observable on `unSubscribe` event?

Answer (score 1):

The observables are properly cleaned up once the last subscription completes. There appears to be nothing wrong with the information you have provided.

Each time you call `getFlowable()`, a new observer chain is created. The `Observable.interval()` operator uses the `Schedulers.computation()` executor to get a new thread to run on.

It isn't clear what you want to happen. Do you want to have the observables run on the same thread? Do you want only a small pool of threads to be used?

Comment: Since the first 2 clients have disconnected I'd expect the corresponding observer chains (ionThreadPool-1, ionThreadPool-2) to disappear. Like when the 3rd client subscribes I can see the ticks from all 3 observer chains for some reason.

Comment: wdym by _last subscription_: The observables are properly cleaned up once the last subscription completes. If there's: subscriber #1 -> connect -> disconnect, subscriber #2 -> connect -> disconnect, #subscriber #3 -> connect (so it's still active), does it count as non-completed last subscription?

Comment: > Do you want only a small pool of threads to be used?
I think it'll make sense, yes.